# Symfony Form Selected Field Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity skill, skill have entity language and relation ManyToMany, I create form  edit and post entity skill in this form, every field empty, but skill have name and language. Why empty field in template?  I not create new, I edit exiting entity. What I'm doing wrong ? When I debug I see skill with not empty field. Help please (((  [sreeen_show](http://uploads.ru/x3YbO.png), [screen_edit](http://uploads.ru/ITFgx.png) 
my action:
In action I try

```
$ln = $entity->getLanguage()->getValues();
```

and have all language for skill, why in form not check this language?

```
  /**
 * Edit skill.
 *
 * @Route("/skills/edit/{id}", name="skill_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template()
 * @ParamConverter("entity", class="MyBundle:Skill")
 */
public function editSkillsAction(Request $request, $entity)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new SkillType(), $entity);
    $form->submit($request);
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('skills_show'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'debug' => true,
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

and form

```
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('skill',  'text', array('label' => 'Skill Name', 'required' => false))
        ->add('mainSkill','checkbox',
            array(
                'label'    => 'Select for Main Skill?',
                'required' => false,)
                );
            $builder->add('language','entity',
                array(
                    'class'=>'My\MyBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages',
                    'property'=>'languages',
                    'multiple'=>true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                     )
            );
    $builder
    ->add('edit','submit')
    ;
}
```

my entity

```
class Skill
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="main_skill", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $mainSkill;

/**
 * @var \Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages", inversedBy="skills", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $language;
```

and CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages

```
class CodeDirectoryProgramLanguages
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="languages", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $languages;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Skill", mappedBy="language")
 */
protected $skills;
```

this my template, very simple

```
{% extends 'MyBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig' %}

{% block form %}

   {{ form(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

**Solved**
in action delete $form->submit($request); and add after if post $form->bind($request);

```
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your ParamConverter don't work fine and don't return the correct entity

Comment: I try $skills = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Skill')->findOneById($id); but have exactly equal from ParamConvertor language={Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection}

Comment: when I do in action $ln = $skills->getLanguage()->getValues(); I see all language for this skill